# Notion of convexity on nonconvex domain?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ be potentially a nonconvex set, and let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\frac{f(x)-f(x')}{x-x'}$ increasing in $x$ and $x'$ for all $x,x'\in X$. Is there a name for this property?

It is satisfied for any convex function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ restricted to the domain $X\subset \mathbb{R}$. But it is not the same as convexity, since convexity is only defined on a convex domain. It does not coincide with superadditivity, since it can be the case that $x,y\in X$, but $x+y \not \in X$.

Comment: I suggest that instate of defining a convex function in a non convex domain attempt for convexification of its domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> convexity is only defined on a convex domain

There is no law against defining a notion of convexity for other domains. For example, [here's a paper](http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/942/Convexity_revision2.pdf) where the authors write

> We say that a real function is convex in a disjoint union of intervals if it is convex in each interval.

which is certainly something they are entitled to do.

The notion you described is more restrictive and, to me at least, more natural than theirs. It is equivalent to saying that $f$ *extends to a convex function on $\mathbb{R}$*. (Indeed, you can fill the gaps between intervals with affine pieces.)

A function that admits a convex extension is sometimes called *convex extensible*, e.g., [here](http://www.cb.uu.se/~kiselman/papersix.pdf). A search shows that this name is also used for other related concepts, so you should not rely on your readers having the same concept of "convex extensible" as you do.